# In awk, how to ignore error line when printing $2, but $2 does not exist in error line

Tags: shell, awk, printing

I have a text file (`xxx.txt`) with this format:

```
kw1 kw2 kw3 kw4
kw1 kw2 kw3 kw4
...
```

but sometimes, the line is abnormal, like this:

```
kw1
```

My shell command is

```
cat xxx.txt|awk '{ print $2;print $3}'
```

How to ignore the abnormal line, and continue printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples try following once. We could use only single print to print the two fields with a new line here

```
awk 'NF>=3{print $2 ORS $3}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

```
awk 'NF>=3{print $2;print $3}' xxx.txt
```

> `NF`:          The number of fields in the current input record.

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

Answering your title question *how to ignore error line when print $2 but $2 it not exist in error line* let `file.txt` content be

```
kw1 kw2 kw3 kw4
kw1 kw2 kw3 kw4
kw1
kw1 kw2 kw3 kw4
```

then

```
awk '($2!=""){print $2;print $3}' file.txt
```

output

```
kw2
kw3
kw2
kw3
kw2
kw3
```

Explanation: if you try to access field which is not present in given line you get empty string. I process lines only where given field is not empty.